# Guest ip is unreachable under Vagrant using private network

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I have next vagrant file on my windows host

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|  
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.customize [
            "modifyvm", :id,
            "--memory", 1024,
            "--cpus", 1,
        ]
    end
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.101"
end
```

Virtual machine starts normally but is unreachable from host by "192.168.0.101" ip. /etc/network/interface on guest is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
      address 192.168.0.101
      netmask 255.255.255.0
#VAGRANT-END
```

and /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0.cfg is

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Additionally after each run that vagrant, the new virtual network adapter is created and inside Virtualbox UI tool I see info about that new network - real IP is diffrent and random i.e. 169.254.173.8. I had >20 virtual networks :) By that IP guest machine is pinged and from itself also. But after restart vagrant the new network will be created with new IP

How to run vagrant machine with static unchangable IP? I need to build cluster with several nodes and each node must know about IP of each one

**Update:**
On Linux host machine all it's OK. I can ping all guests from my host and guets see each other
On Windows guests can't ping other guests i.e. 192.168.0.101 can't see 192.168.0.102

Comment: Did you try to set auto config to false and configure your network adapter manually?

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed

Answer (score 4):

The private network is just that, private to the guest(s), and it's created in addition to the default NAT-ed adapter. If you have several guests, they can interact with each other on the private network.

Regarding the nodes interacting, there are a number of plugins that can help you manage that, both with actual DNS as well as more simply using `/etc/hosts`. I tried a few and settled on [vagrant-hosts](https://github.com/adrienthebo/vagrant-hosts).

Comment: Are you sure that is no way to access from host machine to guest using static IP? Using private network only guests can interact with each other?

Comment: There is a way, just not with the **private** network. It's not recommended as a good security practice, but you can add a [public network](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html) connection, including with a static IP.